# LSH and ORB opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, sift, object-recognition, orb

Basically I have many objects that i would recognize in a test image (query image) using ORB descriptors.

I would like to use LSH to get faster matching but I can't find examples in opencv. 
Is it developed ? What do you use if you have differenet objects and you want to find each of them in a test image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was added in **OpenCV 2.3.1**.

In OpenCV 2.3.1 you can find LSH implemented in `modules/imgproc/src/lsh.cpp`.

In OpenCV 2.4.0 you can find it in `modules/legacy/src/lsh.cpp`.

OpenCV doesn't include a demo for it, but [this thread](http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/how-to-use-the-ORB-descriptor-td6606424.html) discusses it shortly.

Happy Google search!